# iPad: DjVU reader with the support for DropBox?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipad, dropbox

Does there exist an excellent reader for DjVU with the the key property i.e. the support for DropBox so I can download DjVU files easily to it from my DropBox and upload stuff to DropBox from it?

Comment: I haven't found any yet but I have tried most highly-ranked apps. For DropBox support, I know only GoodReader but it does not support DjVU. **Trials** > 1. **[No]** "DjVu Reader" [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/djvu-reader/id417854435?mt=8): does not work.
> > 2. **[No]** DjVu Viewer [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/djvu-viewer/id420344816?mt=8): no search, limited. > 3. **[No]** Stanza [here](http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/stanza/id284956128?mt=8) has poor cross-platform support.

Answer (score 1):

On my iPad, Djvu reader works fine now, and it dates back to in update in August or September.

Comment: Does it have Dropbox support?